# How to enable WCF debugging in the code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a self-hosted WCF service. I don't have an app.config file, instead all the configurations are performed at run time in the code. But I cannot figure out how to enable debugging in the code.

**UPDATE**

I have a VS solution with two projects:

1. WCF service hosted in a WinForms application
2. Simple console client consuming the service

I'd like to be able to start the debugging session in Visual Studio, debug the client, set and hit breakpoints in the service application. I was able to do this when I used app.config files, but now I'd like to do the same without them.

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about tracing and not debugging, right?

Comment: @Elad Lachmi No I'm talking about debugging and stepping inside the service methods.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the debugger to the process that your wcf service is running in.

If in `IIS` you will have to attach to the corresponding w3p.exe process.

If in a stand alone app or windows service, attach to the name of your exe.

In VS in debugger option there is sub option "`attach to process`". You will need to set brak point to the appropriate code and call the service causing that code path to execute.

Can refer this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx

as well as this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17258/Debugging-WCF-Apps

This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to launch debugger from the code, write the following line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

I often use this tecknique in debugging purpose. But it is better to remove it in release version.

If you want to attach to the already running process, open Visual studio, go to menu `Debug > Attach to process`, find the hosting process and click "Attach" button.